# PHP multiple entries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a small project with PHP/MYSQL but i can't get my query working the way i need it. I have 2 tables

Table 1 (char):

```
Id, name.
```

Table 2 (spells):

```
Id, char, spell_name.
```

I'm getting the output:

```
Name Spell1
Name Spell2
Name Spell3
```

But I need it to be:

```
Name Spell1
     Spell2
     Spell3
```

Here's my query:

```
 $query = "SELECT char.name AS name, spells.spell_name AS spell
              FROM char, spells
              WHERE (char.id = spells.spell_name)";
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're gonna have to first get the ID of the character to query, and then pull the spells s/he has access to. Example:

```
$char_id = 0; // value would be assigned arbitrarily.

$query = "SELECT *
FROM 'spells' s
WHERE s.char = $char_id;";

$result = $pdo->query($query);

while($row = $result->fetchObj()){
    // do something with the spells obj here
}
```

With SQL, you need to grab full rows at a time, so I believe the situation you want isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

As Goldentoa11 wrote. Make two selects, or create query with two result sets (more selects in one command), or accept current state (is normal and you can verify data consistency). I prefer current state, but sometimes use any of described solution (based on query frequency, size of result etc.).

If you need to list such data, you can than use something like this:

```
$currentName = null;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
{
    if ($currentName != $row->name)
    {
        echo "<b>" . $row->name . "</b><br />";
        $currentName = $row->name;
    }

    echo $row->spell_name . "<br />";
}
```